# System.TypeInitializationException' error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two projects and I call a function from project2 to the project1 but it shows me the error

> System.TypeInitializationException' error

I have already added the second project to my first but I can't understand what the real problem is.

**1st Project**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Import_from_files42 tr1 = new Import_from_files42();
        tr1.ola();
    }
}
```

**2nd Project**

```
public class Import_from_files42
{
    public void ola()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: are you `using` the correct namespaces?

Comment: yes i have already check this out.

Comment: Cannot tell exactly what would be going wrong here based just on this code... you'll likely need to post a little more here. One thing that could give you this error are 'static' classes, but I don't see one here...

Comment: `System.TypeInitializationException` indicates a problem in a static constructor of some class. use debugger to execute your code line by line and see where it goes wrong

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx), the TypeInitializationException provides access to the original exception. To obtain it, read the **InnerException** property value. The original exception explains the actual cause of the error.